# Is it possible to have a separate Firefox profile for root?

Tags: centos, firefox, privacy

There's a shared office PC that employees can use to surf / look up information on, etc.

There are times when it would be convenient for me to use the same PC to check my email / log into secure sites. These are sites they should not have access to, for instance HR records of other employees.

I have root access on the PC and they don't.

Is there a way for me to do some quick work on the machine and ensure they won't see my saved passwords, etc? For instance, run Firefox as root instead of as the normal user?

Or do I need to log into an entirely different profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given it's a Unix system, CentOS, I would set up myself a separate user account on the system and then run Firefox as this user, as opposed to running it as the shared account that everyone else is using.

Especially given you're accessing confidential information. Leaving this information in the browsers cache and histories is a big no-no to me.

Also I would definitely not use `root` to do anything on this system beyond maintaining it, nor would I use a secondary profile under the same account as everyone else. This provides you little to no benefit.

Additionally I would probably not store any of the passwords etc. on this system either. I would instead use something like [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/), to keep your credentials stored.